# includes exact match item in arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a list of items in an array. I want to add count as postfix at each item by occurrence. I know I'm going to use reduce because I have to compare with previous item, but stuck with includes because it's partial match.

```js
const guest = ["male", "male", "female"]
const r = guest.reduce((accum, g, index) => {

    if(accum.includes(g)) {
        g = g + (index+1)
    } else {
        g = g + index
    }

    accum = [...accum, g]
    return accum

}, []) //expect to be [male1, male2, female1]

console.log('r', r)
```

Comment: with my way. you don't need any temporary count element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to process your array, maintaining a count of the number of times you have seen each guest type and appending that to the value in the array:

```js
const guest = ["male", "male", "female"]

let counts = {}
const r = guest.map(g => {
  counts[g] = (counts[g] || 0) + 1;
  return g + counts[g];
});

console.log('r', r)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are very close, you just need a counter

```
    const guest = ["male", "male", "female"]
    let male = 1;
    let female = 1;
    const r = guest.reduce((accum, g) => {
      if (g === 'male') {
        accum.push(g + male++)
      } else {
        accum.push(g + female++)
      }
      return accum;
    }, []);

    console.log('r', r)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case it may make more sense to store the counts for each gender in an object, then within the reduce function, increment the count, and create your final "guestId" string from the count stored in the object.

This code achieves your desired result:

```js
const guest = ["male", "male", "female"]
const counts = { male: 0, female: 0}
const r = guest.reduce((accum, g, index) => {

  counts[g] += 1
  const guestId = `${g}${counts[g]}`
  accum.push(guestId)
  return accum

}, []) //expect to be [male1, male2, female1]

console.log('r', r)
```

Answer (score 0):

my way... just *array.map* and (you don't need any temporary count element)

```js
const guest = ["male", "male", "female"]
const r = guest.map((c,i,t)=>c+(t.filter((el,ix)=>el===c && ix<i).length +1))

console.log( r.join(' / ') )
```